# How to pass what tableview cell was pressed to other view controllers as navigation title?

Tags: ios, swift

Essentially I have a tableView controller `(VC1)` with cells that have various text in them. When pressed I would like for another view controller `(VC2)` to be pushed and show the text of the cell as the navigation title.

`(VC2)` has a `Next` button on the navigation bar that displays another view controller `(VC3)`

`(VC1)` is making `(VC2)` display its navigation title by doing the following in `didSelectRowAt`

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2")

let navTitle = portfolio.customer
controller.navigationItem.title = navTitle
```

But how can I display that same navigation title in `(VC3)` that is triggered by `(VC2)` ?

```
userdefaults?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you moved from vc1 to vc2 with

```
controller2.navigationItem.title = navTitle
```

You can do

```
controller3.navigationItem.title = self.navigationItem.title // this inside vc2
```

**Tip:**

Don't use userdefaults for storing temporary data

Comment: Should this be placed under the bar button item action? (in vc2)

Comment: For some reason the bar button item when pressed is not executing its action. I've had this issue before so I know it is not the code itself. Any reason this happening?

Comment: can you please take a look at my latest post, I really need some help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756467/issue-properly-triggering-a-view-controller-to-open-when-a-uitableview-row-is-pr?noredirect=1#comment100070687_56756467